# change form fields after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to see and change the inputs of my form after it was submitted i.e. at the .submit event listener.

```
$('.booking-form').submit( function(e){
    var em_booking_form = $(this);
    alert(em_booking_form);
}
```

It prints Object object but i couldn't find how to modify it/its fields. i also tried to flatten it but it just showed couple of Objects.

EDIT: later the form object goes to AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
...
data: em_booking_form.serializeArray(),
...
```

any ideas?

Comment: Why not change the form values BEFORE serializing?

Comment: cant do it, i want to bypass dozens of scripts running of the form.